# Does the same trivially-copyable limitation that applies to `memcpy()` also apply to `std::copy()`?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, memcpy, trivially-copyable

[Cppreference states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), regarding `std::memcpy()` (emphasis added):

> If the objects are potentially-overlapping or not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of `memcpy` **is not specified and may be undefined.**

So, I always check to ensure an object IS trivially-copyable before using `memcpy()`, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "Type T must "
    "be a trivially-copyable type in order to guarantee that `memcpy()` is safe "
    "to use on it.");
memcpy(&outputData, &data, sizeof(data));
```

`std::copy()`, however, doesn't seem to have this limitation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy.

**Does this limitation that the type *must* be trivially-copyable to not have undefined behavior NOT apply to `std::copy()`?**

Also, I just realized [in my "placement new" answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new/63893849#63893849), which made me wonder about this whole thing, I used just `memcpy()` instead of `std::memcpy()`, and I was *not* `using namespace std;`, so which function was called? Is `memcpy()` a different implementation from `std::memcpy()`?

Comment: `std::copy` only has the requirements it says it does.

Comment: Yeah but that's a community wiki, not a C++ standards manual...heck, I edit that wiki on occasion, but I don't even have a standards manual. (Point of my comment: it may be an incomplete wiki, and perhaps this very question will cause someone to update that wiki in case it's lacking information).

Comment: The real Standard costs money to produce so they charge for it. Fortunately they are quite liberal with detailed drafts.: http://eel.is/c++draft/ I used to have a chart somewhere that mapped draft revision numbers that were closest to the approve dStandards, but I've misplaced it.

Comment: Here's the section on std::copy: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.copy

Comment: `memcpy()` copies *raw memory*, so it is undefined for non-trivial data. `std::copy()` copies *elements* and works for complex types that support copy semantics. If the data is trivial, `std::copy()` will use `memcpy()` internally

Answer (score 5):

`memcpy` is a function that copies bytes. `std::copy` copies objects. In some cases, copying the bytes of an object can copy the object.

But these are not the same thing. `std::copy` sees bytewise copying of memory as a potential optimization under certain circumstances in pursuit of its goal: copying objects. It's an implementation detail. For `memcpy`, bytewise copying is *what it does*; that bytewise copying can sometimes copy an object is maybe a side benefit.

It should also be noted that `std::copy` operates on generic iterators. It can "copy" into a `ofstream` via a proper `ostream_iterator`, or it can copy from an `ifstream` via an `istream_iterator`. `std::copy` is not fussy about the source or destination. By contrast, `memcpy` requires that you're copying from and to a contiguous sequence of bytes (and that these sequences are disjoint).

Comment: Notable: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), {}, std::ostrream_iterator<char>(std::cout));` will just directly copy `cin` to `cout`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `std::copy` is a simple standard algorithm. Its general version just uses assignment in a loop, so it is applicable in the same cases as assignment. Library implementers will usually have a special implementation of `std::copy` through `memcpy` when it is safe to do so and is faster than assignment. Since `memcpy` is a legacy C function,  it should almost never be used in C++ outside low-level libraries,.
2. `::memcpy` and `std::memcpy` is really the same thing, because it is coming from C standard library. Formally, you should use `::memcpy` if you `#include <string.h>` and `std::memcpy` if you `#include <cstring>`, but in practice `::memcpy` is always available.